# how to identify names of the partitions

Tags: android, linux

From below partitions how know which partitions is boot and which one is system. Is there any different command I need to execute to read the partitions names.

```
# cat /proc/partitions                                          
major minor  #blocks  name

 253        0     409600 zram0
 179        0   15388672 mmcblk0
 179        1      12772 mmcblk0p1
 179        2      52764 mmcblk0p2
 179        3        128 mmcblk0p3
 179        4        256 mmcblk0p4
 179        5        512 mmcblk0p5
 179        6       2048 mmcblk0p6
 179        7        512 mmcblk0p7
 179        8        512 mmcblk0p8
 179        9      16896 mmcblk0p9
 179       10      13952 mmcblk0p10
 179       11       3072 mmcblk0p11
 179       12       3072 mmcblk0p12
 179       13        780 mmcblk0p13
 179       14        780 mmcblk0p14
 179       15        780 mmcblk0p15
 179       16    2826240 mmcblk0p16
 179       17       8192 mmcblk0p17
 179       18    2119680 mmcblk0p18
 179       19       6144 mmcblk0p19
 179       20      10240 mmcblk0p20
 179       21      10240 mmcblk0p21
 179       22      10240 mmcblk0p22
 179       23       6144 mmcblk0p23
 179       24       3072 mmcblk0p24
 179       25          8 mmcblk0p25
 179       26       9216 mmcblk0p26
 179       27     512000 mmcblk0p27
 179       28      20480 mmcblk0p28
 179       29    9728000 mmcblk0p29
 179       32    1921024 mmcblk1
 179       33    1920000 mmcblk1p1
```

with `df` command

```
  root@android:/ # df
Filesystem             Size   Used   Free   Blksize
/dev                   910M  80.0K   910M   4096
/mnt/secure            910M  0.00K   910M   4096
/mnt/asec              910M  0.00K   910M   4096
/mnt/obb               910M  0.00K   910M   4096
/persdata/absolute    8.82M  4.26M  4.57M   4096
/system               2.66G  2.25G   417M   4096
/data                 9.25G  6.92G  2.33G   4096
/cache                1.99G  39.0M  1.95G   4096
/firmware             86.0M  8.75M  77.2M   16384
/firmware-mdm         86.0M  49.8M  36.2M   16384
/efs                  13.4M  4.23M  9.21M   4096
/mnt/shell/emulated   9.15G  6.92G  2.23G   4096
/mnt/shell/container  9.15G  6.92G  2.23G   4096
/storage/extSdCard    1.83G   758M  1.09G   32768
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `df` command. This will display something like that:

```
# df -h
Filesystem Size Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs 46.9M 0 46.9M 0% /dev
tmpfs 4.0M 0 4.0M 0% /sqlite_stmt_journals
/dev/block/mtdblock1 87.5M 87.5M 0 100% /system
/dev/block/mtdblock2 1.3M 1.1M 120.0k 91% /userdata
/dev/block/mmcblk0p1 944.9M 130.4M 804.9M 14% /data
/dev/block/mtdblock5 35.8M 1.6M 34.2M 4% /dbdata
/dev/block/mtdblock4 87.5M 4.9M 82.6M 6% /cache
/dev/block/vold/180:2
6.6G 2.7G 3.8G 41% /sdcard
/dev/block/vold/179:9
7.6G 1.5G 6.1G 19% /sdcard/sd
```

The second option would be to read the  `/proc/self/mountinfo` file.

Comment: but on Android device only df is working option -h is not supported.

Comment: It doesn't matter, `-h` stands for human readable, so it displays Megabytes instead of kilobytes.

Comment: I have edited my question with df output.. you mean to compare the size to match name(s) and paritions block(s)? but still doesnt reveal the boot partition

Comment: Instead of reading `/proc/self/mountinfo` I'd just use `mount`.

Answer (score 1):

for my device(Sony Xperia Z2), in directory `/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name` , there are documents named system, cache, etc.every file is linked to a partition.
and I got this table:

```
major   minor   #blocks     name            
179     0       15267840    mmcblk0
179     1       2048        mmcblk0p1       TA
179     2       512         mmcblk0p2
179     3       256         mmcblk0p3       s1sbl
179     4       64          mmcblk0p4       dbi
179     5       512         mmcblk0p5       aboot
179     6       512         mmcblk0p6       rpm
179     7       512         mmcblk0p7
179     8       512         mmcblk0p8       alt_sbl1
179     9       256         mmcblk0p9       alt_s1sbl
179     10      64          mmcblk0p10      alt_dbi
179     11      512         mmcblk0p11      alt_aboot
179     12      512         mmcblk0p12      alt_rpm
179     13      512         mmcblk0p13      alt_tz
179     14      20480       mmcblk0p14      boot
179     15      10240       mmcblk0p15      ramdump
179     16      16384       mmcblk0p16      FOTAKernel
179     17      32          mmcblk0p17      DDR
179     18      16384       mmcblk0p18      LTALabel
179     19      1536        mmcblk0p19      modemst1
179     20      1536        mmcblk0p20      modemst2
179     21      1536        mmcblk0p21      fsg
179     22      8192        mmcblk0p22      apps_log
179     23      2609152     mmcblk0p23      system
179     24      204800      mmcblk0p24      cache
179     25      12359663    mmcblk0p25      userdata
179     32      4096        mmcblk0rpmb
179     64      30915584    mmcblk1
179     65      30914560    mmcblk1p1
```